# Will I need to redo/repair drywall if I renovate my kitchen entirely?

Tags: drywall, kitchens, cabinets, kitchen-counters

So my girlfriend and I bought a new house and we're renovating the kitchen entirely. We do business with a fairly high-end company that will take care of things like counters, cabinets, ceramic on the ground and the wall, etc. but along with a friend of mine that's a contractor we'll demolish the current kitchen entirely because demolition and cleaning is not included. Basically, we remove everything and make it a completely empty room.

So my question is, will I have to repair or redo the drywalls behind the cabinets and counters or should I be good with just putting on primer.

Of course that's assuming there are no holes or anything like that. Also the house is 20 years old.

I just want to know if I need to buy drywall because where I live there is currently a shortage caused by everyone renovating all at once during Covid so we have to order months in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you won't need to replace all the drywall if you're careful when you do your demolition. A 20 year old home has modern drywall that should still be in good condition. The exception would be anywhere that requires major plumbing or electrical access, for example.

I suggest that you have a few sheets on hand for patch repairs, but you won't need to redo the whole thing. You will likely need to do some skimming and possibly texturing before you paint.

Comment: I'd agree, except that in some jurisdictions, kitchen electrical codes have changed massively over 20 years. You might find that the electrician would be excavating so substantially that it's easier to just re-rock the whole thing.